# Time synchronization problem in two operating systems

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, upgrade

I have two operating systems in my machine: Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04, dual booted. After upgrading my ubuntu to 16.04 version from 15.10, I am facing a strange problem. When I open Ubuntu, time advances 5.30 hours(I am from India and our timezone is +5.30GMT). Suppose I correct it, then when I logs back in Windows, the time decreased by 5.40 hours.

How to fix it? There might be some installation problem at the time of upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu uses GMT while Windows uses your local time-zone.

To fix this, you'll want to reboot into Windows, open start and type regedit, then tap `enter`. From there, navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation`.

Next, if you don't see an entry that reads `RealTimeIsUniversal`, then add one by right-clicking > New > DWORD (32-bit) Value, then fill in the name `RealTimeIsUniversal`.

Now double-click the entry you just added, and replace the `0` with a `1`.

Make sure the time is correct in Windows, then reboot.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Or, from the Ubuntu side...

```
You can set the hardware clock time standard through the terminal command line.

You can check what you have set to use by:

$ timedatectl

To change the hardware clock time standard to localtime, use:

# timedatectl set-local-rtc 1

If you want to revert to the hardware clock being in UTC, do:

# timedatectl set-local-rtc 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Ubuntu uses UTC( or GMT) while Windows uses Local time. So every time you alternate between the OSes, the OS would reset the system clock in its own way. So you have to either configure Ubuntu to use localtime or force Windows to use UTC.

The procedure to do so is documented clearly in the following link http://www.webupd8.org/2014/09/dual-boot-fix-time-differences-between.html

The advantages of using UTC over local-time is that you don't need to change your system time every time you travel between different time zones. If you don't travel much out of India, you could use either of the methods described in the link or just type
`timedatectl set-local-rtc 1`    in the ubuntu terminal. This command will force ubuntu to use localtime.